# Why my ping dont let me see the IP? maybe because im in job network?

Tags: cmd, ip

[CMD][https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Mut.png]

I saw on youtube the others guys doesnt have it

Comment: so how can i see the ip address of my friend using cmd and same network , i saw in youtube and they tracers the machine name and ip appears

Comment: There is an IP. And this is off topic on StackOverflow. Oh yeah and please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is `ping -4 my-pc` for ipV4, that's your [ipV6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Comment: OHHHHH THX MATE

Comment: i can up vote sry